# Only one image showing on product page - Mage 1.9 CE

Tags: product, image, product-images, product-view

Basically I no matter how many image I add I only seem to display one image on the front end on the product view.

I have tried across templates so imagine this is related to the config in Magento.

Can someone please help! I'm a bit of a noob to Mage!

Comment: You try to clear Magento cache? You can take a screenshot your backend product image setting?

Comment: Do you want only one image on product view page. you don't want more images?

Comment: Its matter on how many images you add in backend for product. Replace Media.phtml from fresh magento zip folder.

Answer (score 0):

please look media.phtml located in

`magento_root/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Check the images tab in your product edit page and make sure that the 'exclude' checkbox is unchecked for any additional images you want to show.

Then, in the upper left hand corner is a store view selector. Select each store view one at a time and check the exclude checkboxes. They could very well be checked for a specific store view , if not the default settings.